# Handling PostgreSQL foreign key errors vs. preventing them from occuring

Tags: sql, postgresql

Do I really need to check that the the record in another table really exist, if PostgreSQL will check that foreign key constraint anyway?

Normaly you check if there is existing `parent` record, before creating `child` record. But it's another query to execute. So I think if it would be better to just handle the PostgreSQL error and check if it was about that the `parent` record doesn't exist (violates foreign key constraint).

Is it better to utilize database server capabilities, or it was not ment for this purpose?
Do you recommend to do all the integrity checking before creating new record?

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."categories" (
    "id" serial,
    "name" varchar(100),
    CONSTRAINT "categories__id_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

CREATE TABLE "public"."products" (
    "id" serial,
    "category_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar(100),
    CONSTRAINT "products__id_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
    CONSTRAINT "products__category_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("category_id")
        REFERENCES "categories" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

A pseudo-code:

```
if (query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = 123"))
    query("INSERT INTO products (category_id, name) VALUES (123, 'Something')")
else
    throw Error("Parent record does not exist")

try
    query("INSERT INTO products (category_id, name) VALUES (123, 'Something')")
catch (Exception e)
    if (e.code == '23503')
        throw Error("Parent record does not exist")
    else
        throw Error("Some other error occured")
```

Error code `23503` in PostgreSQL is:

`ERROR: insert or update on table "products" violates foreign key constraint "products__category_id_fkey"`

Comment: @danihp what do you mean? In this case there is no need for triggers. Integrity check is done automatically by foreign key constraint. The question is how should I check if the parent record exists - by making extra select query before the insert query, or by handling PostgreSQL errors returned on insert query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks about your comment. Deleted all comments.

Comment: @Taai If you do a select-then-insert you have a race condition where another connection could insert/delete/update the row between when you select for it and when you insert it. You must still handle errors unless you `LOCK` the table, so you might as well forgo the select and *just* handle errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Is it better to utilize database server capabilities, or it was not ment for this purpose*

It was **exactly** meant for that purpose.

Just handle the error, otherwise you are doing too much work.

If you check for the existense of the related rows, you just duplicate the work as PostgreSQL will also do that.

If you don't want to care in which order you insert the rows, you can declare the constraint as `deferrable initially deferred`. In that case all related rows must exist when you *commit* your transaction, not when you run each statement. Here is a short example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/33de1/1

In that case you need handle errors when you commit, not when you run each statement.